# I need some help formatting a file in an organized way

Tags: c++, io

I'm writing a program to update, delete and list all tools from a hardware store in a file. I'm able to update and list all the tools in the file but they are in a very unorganized format on the screen. Here is my code to output. Could someone give me an idea on how to format this so the headers in the file line up more evenly? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "HardWare.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int ch = 0, count=0, rNo, qty;
 string fileName, h1, h2, h3, h4,hName;
 double c;
 ifstream inFile;
 ofstream outFile;
 HardwareData hwd[10];

 cout<<endl<<endl<<"Enter 1 for opening data file."<<endl;
 cout<<"Enter 2 to list all records."<<endl;
 cout<<"Enter 3 to add a record."<<endl;
 cout << "Enter 4 to delete an entry."<<endl; 
 cout<<"Enter 5 to exit the program."<<endl;

 cout<<"Choice: ";

 cin>>ch;

 while(ch!=5)
 {
      switch(ch)
      {
      case 1:
          inFile.open("Hardware.dat");
          if(!inFile)            
          break;
      case 2:
          {               
               while(!inFile.eof())
               {
               inFile>>h1>>h2>>h3>>h4;          
               cout<<h1<<"\t"<<h2<< "\t"<<h3<<"\t"<<h4 <<endl;                  
               }
          }
          break;
```

this is the hardware.dat file

```
Record_num    Tool_name   Quantity    Cost
3        Electric Sander    7       57.98
17          Hammer          76      11.99
24          Jig Saw         21      11.00
39          Lawn Mower      3       79.50
56          Power Saw       18      99.99
68          Screwdriver     106     6.99
77          Sledge Hammer   11      21.50
83          Wrench          34      7.50
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you give us an example of `Hardware.dat`, so that we can see what you're talking about? (You can hit `edit` at the bottom of your question and add the new text.)

Comment: Look at `std::setw()`, it's part of `iomanip`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setw(n)` to adjust the space taken up by each field you it will space them correctly, provided `n` is greater than the maximum number of characters in that field.

I believe the output is auto aligned left, but if not you will need to add in `std::left` as well (or just `left` since you are using the namespace `std`).

```
while(!inFile.eof())
{
    inFile>>h1>>h2>>h3>>h4;         
    cout << setw(10) << h1;
    cout << setw(10) << h2;
    cout << setw(10) << h3;
    cout << setw(10) << h4;
    cout << endl;      
    // cout <<h1<<"\t"<<h2<< "\t"<<h3<<"\t"<<h4 <<endl;                  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the format issue, but for some reason, my output now is not correct. It seems completely random. The tool names are not under the tool name header etc. Would you suggest a better way of reading the data in from the file?

Comment: @PerrinHawver Could you add what your new output appears like to the question?

Comment: @PerrinHawver It is either because of one or both of the following. The value of `n` in `setw(n)` is too small ("Electric Sander") is 15 characters so for that field your value of `n` needs to be at least 15. Or it could be that the window you are printing the output to is too small and so the output overflows onto the next line, make the window larger before printing to it.